# How to add textfile download button in Javascript DataTables?

Tags: javascript, datatables, export

I need to add a button to download the datatable content as a text file. I have only one column in the datatable. My code is given below. Copy, excel, csv, pdf and print are working properly with below code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('#dataTableExample').DataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copyHtml5', footer: true
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5', footer: true
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5', footer: true
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5', footer: true
                }
            ],

        });
    });
```

Comment: You may use the [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355) in SO and provide a working example for people to understand your question more easily

Answer (score 2):

The [built-in](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/built-in) DataTables buttons don't support exporting a single column as a plain text file. You can however achieve this by defining your own button with a [custom action](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.action).

The snippet below should achieve what you are looking for, it can be added to the `buttons` array passed to `DataTable` on setup. This adds a button named 'TXT' which takes the filtered values from the first column in the table, joins then with CR+LF, and then triggers a download of the result as a .txt file.

```js
{
  text: 'TXT',
  action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
    // Generate the text to be exported
    // Please note...
    // - This only takes column 0
    // - The output is filtered based on the applied search
    // - This doesn't include the header or footer
    // - This uses CR+LF line endings
    let text = dt.columns(0, { search: 'applied' }).data().toArray()[0].join('\r\n');

    // Add an element to the page contianing the encoded txt to download
    // click the element to trigger the download, then remove the element
    let element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', 'data.txt');
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
  }
}
```

A working example can be seen at https://jsfiddle.net/a3eucptL/.